# group base query on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]
i need to select all the value but for each tow of them there is different conditions...

```
SELECT `csn`,`lsn` FROM `critical_limits` WHERE `limits` = 'vl'
```

and

```
SELECT `csp`,`lsp` FROM `critical_limits` WHERE `limits` = 'm'
```

and store them in a single array.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample results.

Comment: i mean i need the value of csn,lsn,csp,lsp,cks,lsk... rest of them but for cns,lsn or csp,lsp i need different condition which i compare in limits column.

Comment: What did you try, what exactly went wrong, ... --> [ask]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
SELECT `csn`,`lsn` FROM `critical_limits` WHERE `limits` = 'vl'
UNION ALL
SELECT `csp`,`lsp` FROM `critical_limits` WHERE `limits` = 'm';
```

Note:  `union` incurs overhead to remove duplicates.  Usually this is not desired, so you should use `union all`.

An alternative is a bunch of `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN limits = 'vl' THEN csn ELSE csp END) as cs,
       (CASE WHEN limits = 'vl' THEN lsn ELSE lsp END) as lsp
FROM `critical_limits`
WHERE `limits` IN ('m', 'vl')
```

Comment: thank you for your reply..
its working with UNION but the second query (csp and lsp) value goes under (csn and lsn) as a new row...
csn          lsn
0.09          0
7.5          15.1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `csn`,
    `lsn`
FROM
    `critical_limits`
WHERE
    `limits` = 'vl'
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        `csp`,
        `lsp`
    FROM
        `critical_limits`
    WHERE
        `limits` = 'm'
```

You can use `UNION` to combine queries. [UNION in the MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

You need to have the same count of columns in your `SELECT` and the columns must have the same datatype.